# CodeIgniter file input not being picked up

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a simple image upload form, which isn't detecting an image being posted. I'm sure there's something I'm missing but I just can't seem to find it. Code below:

Form file:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart( 'account/uploadimage' ) ?>

    <?php echo form_label('Image', 'userfile'); ?>

    <input name="userfile" type="file" />                   

    <div class="formSubmit clearfix">
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Update'); ?>
    </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller "/account/uploadimage"

```
var_dump( $this->input->post('userfile') ); // bool(false)
echo "<hr>";
var_dump( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ); // The info I'm after
```

I want to make use of the Codeigniter facilities, so need $this->input->post('userfile') to work.

Any ideas as to why it gives me false?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this won't work:

```
var_dump( $this->input->post('userfile') );
```

because user uploaded files are stored inside the $_FILES variable and not $_POST

just use the codeigniter's upload library

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Providing correct code is very much helpful for newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this---

```
    if( ! is_dir(UPLOAD_PATH.'folder') ){mkdir(UPLOAD_PATH.'folder',0777,TRUE); };      
    $path=UPLOAD_PATH.'folder/';        
    $imgtmpname=$_FILES['eposter']['tmp_name'];
    $fullpath= $path .$imgname;
    $filename = $imgname;

    move_uploaded_file($imgtmpname,$fullpath);
```